# Three.js: Possible to flip a sprite?

Tags: three.js

**Question**: Is it possible to flip/mirror a Three.js sprites texture?

**Background**: Using the current DEV branch of three.js

**Findings so far**: I first try'd to change it's 3d rotation without any effect. Then I inspected the sprites code and saw that the rotation is reseted in this line in Sprite.js:

```
this.rotation3d.set( 0, 0, this.rotation );
```

Changing the values there didn't had any effect. Digging deeper I ended up in the SpriteRenderer plugin where I got completely lost.

My understanding is that three.js is using shaders to render sprites and that this is a huge performance plus. So writing my own sprite implementation using simple faces feels like the wrong direction.

Comment: You could always supply your own `ShaderMaterial` for THREE sprite, but it seems like an overkill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okey, this is a long shot, but try setting your sprite's **scale** to -1 (in the directions you want to flip it).

Answer (score 3):

Just posting it as an alternative:

```
texture = new three60.THREE.Texture(video);
texture.repeat.set(-1, 1);
texture.offset.set( 1, 0);
```

Comment: This worked for me w/ a video texture that was on the BackSide of a SphereGeometry.

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way to flip a texture is actually to flip the texture image before uploading to the GPU.

Comment: That's so lame, actually :)

Comment: But by far the easiest way to do it, even if you have to do it in runtime.

Comment: If my answer works (I'm not sure and not quite able to test it right now), I'd argue.

Comment: I guess this would work too. But i have to do the flip after the texture is loaded to the GPU. Think of a plattformer with a entity facing different directions. Barteks answer works really well. But thanks anyway :)