# How to flip the texture of a sprite along the x axis three js?

Tags: three.js

I need to flip a sprite texture in the scene.

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052047/three-js-possible-to-flip-a-sprite), I should be able to set the scale to -1 in the direction that is needed to flip (x).

I wrote 2 examples that load a sprite with a texture:

- In the [first](https://jsfiddle.net/avnerm/1Lz4ux3k/43/) case the scale is set to (1000, 1000, 1)
- In the [second](https://jsfiddle.net/avnerm/1Lz4ux3k/44/) case the scale is set to (-1000, 1000, 1)

In the second case, scale.x is negated, so I expect the image to be flipped (mirrored) on the x axis, but the image still looks the same as in the first case.

**How can I flip the texture of the sprite along the x axis?**

---

EDIT:
I found out that I can flip the image by using [flipY](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.flipY) (I did not find flipX) and rotating the image by 180 degrees.
See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/avnerm/1Lz4ux3k/45/)

**Is this an acceptable way to flip the image?**

Thanks,
Avner

`1`

Answer (score 4):

Unlike with meshes, it's not possible to use `Sprite.scale` to render it mirrored. The recommended way of doing this is by transforming texture coordinates by setting `Texture.repeat` to `(-1, 1)` and `Texture.center` to `(0.5, 0.5)`.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
    camera.position.z = 1;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
  
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var map = loader.load( 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg' );
    map.center.set( 0.5, 0.5 );
    map.repeat.set( - 1, 1 );

    var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: map } );

    var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( material );
    scene.add( sprite );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.116.1/build/three.js"></script>
```